# How to make content 100% between header and footer with scrollbar

Tags: css

I have header, footer and the content. I want my content (section) to always be between header and a footer with scrollbar (overflow: auto) , the height should be 100% minus header and the footer.

I've try:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/puXMMicg9e0PqFebk0o0?p=preview)

Comment: adding overflow-y: auto; in the section style should solve the issue.

Comment: @unixmiah I already have overflow on section. but I got padding inside a box with scrollbar and I want my scrollbar to be between header and a footer.

Comment: Are you going to have a fixed height on the body or do you want it to be 100% of the space between the header and footer regardless of the screen size?

Comment: @MattWhiteley 100% of the space between the header and footer regardless of the screen size

Comment: ahh. you want fixed scrolling between header and footer/content scrolling: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-content-scrolling--mobile-8332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
section {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  bottom: 89px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close...You need to absolutely position the `<div>` inside the section, along with a few other small changes to your syntax:

```
section {
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   bottom:120px;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
section div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Should probably clean up the code a bit, but this should accomplish the scroll between the header/footer that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very light weight solution I built for you, I imagine you can build nearly anything on top of this, as well as modify it to suit to your needs:

CSS

```
body {
    margin-top:50px;
}
.header-fixed, .footer-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    background:pink;
    padding:10px;
}
.header-fixed {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.footer-fixed {
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header-fixed">Header</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat efficitur mollis. Quisque convallis ipsum nunc, id pulvinar neque interdum eget. Donec dignissim nec leo ac gravida. Cras dictum sapien eu mi dapibus pulvinar. Sed ut pretium nibh. Etiam vitae ultrices erat, nec finibus leo. Aliquam ultrices lectus ac nulla rhoncus accumsan. Pellentesque gravida, tellus id condimentum maximus, eros justo cursus tortor, sed ornare nisl est vel erat. Maecenas finibus nibh enim, vitae semper magna ornare sit amet. Integer ultricies rhoncus congue. Aliquam quis neque in nisi laoreet eleifend ac ac neque. Vivamus erat est, elementum sed urna ac, euismod aliquam tortor.
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat efficitur mollis. Quisque convallis ipsum nunc, id pulvinar neque interdum eget. Donec dignissim nec leo ac gravida. Cras dictum sapien eu mi dapibus pulvinar. Sed ut pretium nibh. Etiam vitae ultrices erat, nec finibus leo. Aliquam ultrices lectus ac nulla rhoncus accumsan. Pellentesque gravida, tellus id condimentum maximus, eros justo cursus tortor, sed ornare nisl est vel erat. Maecenas finibus nibh enim, vitae semper magna ornare sit amet. Integer ultricies rhoncus congue. Aliquam quis neque in nisi laoreet eleifend ac ac neque. Vivamus erat est, elementum sed urna ac, euismod aliquam tortor.
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat efficitur mollis. Quisque convallis ipsum nunc, id pulvinar neque interdum eget. Donec dignissim nec leo ac gravida. Cras dictum sapien eu mi dapibus pulvinar. Sed ut pretium nibh. Etiam vitae ultrices erat, nec finibus leo. Aliquam ultrices lectus ac nulla rhoncus accumsan. Pellentesque gravida, tellus id condimentum maximus, eros justo cursus tortor, sed ornare nisl est vel erat. Maecenas finibus nibh enim, vitae semper magna ornare sit amet. Integer ultricies rhoncus congue. Aliquam quis neque in nisi laoreet eleifend ac ac neque. Vivamus erat est, elementum sed urna ac, euismod aliquam tortor.
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed placerat efficitur mollis. Quisque convallis ipsum nunc, id pulvinar neque interdum eget. Donec dignissim nec leo ac gravida. Cras dictum sapien eu mi dapibus pulvinar. Sed ut pretium nibh. Etiam vitae ultrices erat, nec finibus leo. Aliquam ultrices lectus ac nulla rhoncus accumsan. Pellentesque gravida, tellus id condimentum maximus, eros justo cursus tortor, sed ornare nisl est vel erat. Maecenas finibus nibh enim, vitae semper magna ornare sit amet. Integer ultricies rhoncus congue. Aliquam quis neque in nisi laoreet eleifend ac ac neque. Vivamus erat est, elementum sed urna ac, euismod aliquam tortor.
</p>
<div class="footer-fixed">
    Footer
</div>
```